# First x tick tabel is not shown when using xticklabels from tabels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, pgfkeys

I have the following code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{./data/crash_1987.csv}{\loadedtable};

\begin{axis}[
    width=20cm,
    height=8cm,
    grid=both,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    % no marks,
    xticklabels from table={\loadedtable}{Date},
    xtick distance={1},
    x tick label style={rotate=90},
    y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/precision=5
    },
    scaled y ticks=false,
    legend style={at={(0.025,0.95)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel={Value (\$)},
    y label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)}, anchor=south, rotate=-90}
]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{SP 500}{
    \addplot+[ultra thick] table [x expr=\coordindex, y=#1] {\loadedtable};
    \addlegendentry{#1};
}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

that produces the plot,

[image]

using the data

```
Date,SP 500,DIJA
1987-10-06,319.220001,2548.629883
1987-10-07,318.540009,2551.080078
1987-10-08,314.160004,2516.639893
1987-10-09,311.070007,2482.209961
1987-10-12,309.390015,2471.439941
1987-10-13,314.519989,2508.159912
1987-10-14,305.230011,2412.699951
1987-10-15,298.079987,2355.090088
1987-10-16,282.700012,2246.729980
1987-10-19,224.839996,1738.739990
1987-10-20,236.830002,1841.010010
1987-10-21,258.380005,2027.849976
1987-10-22,248.250000,1950.430054
1987-10-23,248.220001,1950.760010
1987-10-26,227.669998,1793.930054
1987-10-27,233.190002,1846.489990
1987-10-28,233.279999,1846.819946
1987-10-29,244.770004,1938.329956
1987-10-30,251.789993,1993.530029
1987-11-02,255.750000,2014.089966
1987-11-03,250.820007,1963.530029
1987-11-04,248.960007,1945.290039
1987-11-05,254.479996,1985.410034
```

The first x tick label won't show on the graph. How can I change this, so the plot doesn't match coordinates like (x_{n+1}, y_n)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to add `xtick=data`. Then everything works as expected.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{crash_1987.csv}
Date,SP 500,DIJA
1987-10-06,319.220001,2548.629883
1987-10-07,318.540009,2551.080078
1987-10-08,314.160004,2516.639893
1987-10-09,311.070007,2482.209961
1987-10-12,309.390015,2471.439941
1987-10-13,314.519989,2508.159912
1987-10-14,305.230011,2412.699951
1987-10-15,298.079987,2355.090088
1987-10-16,282.700012,2246.729980
1987-10-19,224.839996,1738.739990
1987-10-20,236.830002,1841.010010
1987-10-21,258.380005,2027.849976
1987-10-22,248.250000,1950.430054
1987-10-23,248.220001,1950.760010
1987-10-26,227.669998,1793.930054
1987-10-27,233.190002,1846.489990
1987-10-28,233.279999,1846.819946
1987-10-29,244.770004,1938.329956
1987-10-30,251.789993,1993.530029
1987-11-02,255.750000,2014.089966
1987-11-03,250.820007,1963.530029
1987-11-04,248.960007,1945.290039
1987-11-05,254.479996,1985.410034
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{crash_1987.csv}{\loadedtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=20cm,
        height=8cm,
        grid=both,
        enlarge x limits=false,
        xtick=data,         % <-- added
        xticklabels from table={\loadedtable}{Date},
        x tick label style={rotate=90},
        legend style={at={(0.025,0.95)},anchor=north west},
        ylabel={Value (\$)},
        y label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)}, anchor=south, rotate=-90},
    ]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{SP 500}{
            \addplot+ [ultra thick]
                table [x expr=\coordindex, y=#1] {\loadedtable};
            \addlegendentry{#1};
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]