# Wrong position xticklabels with un-intact data

Tags: pgfplots

The following MWE making a plot by `pgfplots` shows `xticktables` in wrong position along the x-axis. I think this is caused by lost data. So, is there a approach to make these xticktables in right position regardless lost data.

PS: the given soluntion above [First x tick tabel is not shown when using xticklabels from tabels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380486/first-x-tick-tabel-is-not-shown-when-using-xticklabels-from-tabels) 
does not solve my problem. I tried by adding `xtick=data`, the lost data still causes wrong position of xticklable from "c".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents} 

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{test.dat} 
id,note,a
1,a,1
2,b,4
3,c,
4,d,16
5,e,25
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
table/col sep=comma,
title={example},
xlabel=id,
ylabel={$data$},
xticklabel style={rotate=90},
xticklabels from table={test.dat}{note},
% xticklabels={a,b,c,d,e} % I also tried this, but still fail.
]
\addplot [blue,mark=*] table[x=id,y=a] {test.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried. The problem is still there without "lost" data. I believe this simpler example gives same problem: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{test.dat} 
1 11
2 22
3 33
4 44
\end{filecontents}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xticklabels={1,...,4}]
\addplot table {test.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: I do not know why there is this behaviour, but the the problem goes away, if you actually specify the position of the ticks and not just the labels : `\begin{axis}[xtick={1,...,4}, xticklabels={1,...,4}]...`

Comment: Please reconsider (test), if your problem has something to do with "lost data" / "un-intact data" and edit your title.

Comment: @hpekristiansen The example in my post has only 5 lines of data. In fact I have to deal with nealy 10 thousands of lines. And xticklabels are not numbers. So is thhere a better way to define every xticklabel?

Comment: `c` doesn' work because an empty "cell" in a table is not allowed. Add `NaN` there and it will work.

Comment: Thank you @Stefan Pinnow. As I need to handle nearly 10 thousnds of data lines in which about 25% lines have no data. So it's a large job to fill each empty "cell" with NaN.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot change the format which is required for PGFPlots ... But I guess that there is the possibility to do some "search and replace" to bring it in good shape.